# GitHub - How to create new repository from subdirectory of another repository and keep both synced

Tags: git, github, synchronization, subdirectory

I am wondering if it is possible to have the following setup:

1. A repository that has many client folders that all contain
   various data, projects, etc. (Repo A)
2. Create a new repository from just ONE of the above mentioned client folders. (Repo B)
3. When pushing updates from Repo B locally to GitHub, also have it pushed/synced to Repo A's directory for that client

Is this possible?
If so, how would I properly go about it?

For now I am just working strictly on Repo B, then copy and pasting to Repo A's client folder.
Would prefer a more efficient and automatic method if possible.

Comment: `git subtree` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize another repository in the desired subdirectory (that is already under the parent repo) and commit/push both repositories as normal.